# django: Override get_Form inlines

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inlines

I want to override the `get_form` in a tabular admin in order to filter by current user.
The thing is that I'm getting a error:

```
 object has no attribute 'current_user'
```

- Admin.py

  ```
  class InvoiceDetail(admin.TabularAdmin):
      form = InvoiceDetailForm
      model = fa_invoice_lines

      def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
          form = super(InvoiceDetail, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
          form.current_user = request.user
          return form

  class Invoice(admin.ModelAdmin)
      form = InvoiceForm
      inlines =   [InvoiceDetail,]
  ```
- Form.py

  ```
  class InvoiceDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(InvoiceDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['item'].queryset = fa_items.objects.filter(tenant=self.current_user)

      class Meta:
          model = fa_invoice_lines
  ```

I have used the same strategy in not inlines and it works
It seems is not calling the `get_form`

Comment: I see that "some help" is given but I also understand that it is not appreciated or even accepted.

Answer (score 6):

`admin.TabularAdmin` does not have a `get_form` method.
The `get_form` function you defined is never being called.

You might want to look into `get_formset` method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_formset

Answer (score 5):

Inspired from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines), I have implemented the following solution:

```
class Invoice(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = InvoiceForm
    inlines =   [InvoiceDetail,]

def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
    for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
        inline.form.current_user = request.user
        yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
```